# RegEx of email address with additional domains with JQuery Vaildate

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-validate

I need to validate an email address with extra domains.  I validate currently a normal email with `@email.com`, but I need to validate an email that has `@email.email.com`.  I am not familiar with RegEx enough.

```
$.validator.addMethod('matches', function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value.match(param);
},
'Please enter a valid value.');

$(function() {

 $("form").validate({

            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    matches: '.+@email.com'
                }
            }, messages: {
                email: {
                    matches: 'Must be a email.com e-mail address.'
                }
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: @Andreas - you should post that (with a brief explanation) as an answer. My short answer: don't bother using regex to "validate" an email address, as (1) you're going to get it wrong and exclude valid email addresses (like xvatar does in that answer) and (2) you have to send a confirmation test message anyway.

Comment: @Andreas - thank you, but I already know these sites.  I'm just having trouble getting the emails that have like `@testemail.com` instead of @test.email.com

Comment: @StephenP -  I have a specific style of emails I need to match its not as bad as it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for jquery validate to validate that email belongs to the organization.  I was really close, but I didn't think it would need a few things.

```
(.+@+[A-Za-z0-9._-]+\\.email.com$)|(.+@email.com$)
```

Answer (score 1):

To match any (usual) email with a two part top-level-domain, like `*@google.co.uk` you could use a RegExp, that matches 2-3 word parts in the domain section:

```
var emailRegExp = /[a-zA-Z0-9._-]@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.\w+(\.\w+)?/
...
// in your code
matches: emailRegExp
```

The RegExp explained:

- The name part `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]` will match any usual characters, as well as `.`, `_` and `-`
- The domain name part `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` is about the same as the name, but without `.` or `_`
- The top-level-domain part `\.\w+(\.\w+)?` will match any single tld like `.com`, `.net`, etc. as well as the double ones `.co.uk`, `.co.jp`, `.foo.bar`

The RegExp is a quite short one. 
If you are really interested in the correct email verification you should take a look at the [RFC822-Spec](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) (SCNR :D)

Comment: I'm just looking to validate a specific email.

Comment: Then perhaps the answer of xvatar is what you were looking for.

Comment: yes, jquery validate already validates the email address, but I"m trying to validate if its an internal email or not.